# WSO2 Identity Server - Active Directory Integration - Change Password Issue

Tags: active-directory, wso2, wso2-identity-server

So I've been doing some testing with the latest version of WSO2 IS (5.3.0), just running locally on my laptop.

I've set up AD integration, and set up the LDAP bind account user with Delegated Control to reset passwords on a specific OU, and the objects therein. That same LDAP bind account is also configured as an INTERNAL/admin account.

When either of the two users within the specific OU mentioned above log in, they can change their password. The admin account that I am using, can find them, but can NOT change their password (in AD terminology, "RESET PASSWORD", even though it should be able to.

Here's my user-mgt.xml (I've removed the large blocks that are commented out):

```
    <UserManager>
    <Realm>
        <Configuration>
        <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
            <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
            <AdminUser>
                <UserName>ADMIN</UserName>
                <Password>PASSWORD</Password>
            </AdminUser>
            <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
            <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">false</Property>
 <!-- <Property name="initializeNewClaimManager">true</Property> -->
            <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
        </Configuration>

        <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
            <!-- <Property name="AnonymousBind">false</Property> -->
            <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionName">CN=ADMIN,OU=DEPARTMENT,OU=USERS,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">PASSWORD</Property>
            <!-- <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">false</Property> -->
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">LDAPS://DC.EXAMPLE.COM:636</Property>
            <Property name="defaultRealmName">EXAMPLE.COM</Property>
            <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute">sAMAccountName</Property>
            <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
            <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">group</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectcategory=group)</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=group)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">OU=EXAMPLE GROUPS,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM</Property>
            <Property name="isADLDSRole">false</Property>
            <Property name="IsBulkImportSupported">false</Property>
            <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <!-- <Property name="MemberOfAttribute">memberOf</Property> -->
            <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
            <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <!-- <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password length should be within 5 to 30 characters</Property> -->
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="ReadTimeout"/>
            <Property name="Referral">follow</Property>
            <Property name="RetryAttempts"/>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
            <!-- <Property name="userAccountControl">512</Property> -->
            <Property name="userAccountControl">66048</Property>
            <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">user</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">sAMAccountName</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <!-- <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated</Property> -->
            <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=user)</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=?))</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">OU=EXAMPLE Users,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM</Property>
            <Property name="WriteGroups">false</Property>
        </UserStoreManager>

        <AuthorizationManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
            <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
            <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">true</Property>
        </AuthorizationManager>
    </Realm>
</UserManager>
```

And here's my debug:

```
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,466] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Authorization cache miss for username : ADMIN resource /permission/admin/manage/identity/usermgt/update action : ui.execute
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,467] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Allowed roles for the ResourceID: /permission/admin/manage/identity/usermgt/update Action: ui.execute
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,467] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  role: INTERNAL/admin
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,467] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Roles which have permission for resource : /permission/admin/manage/identity/usermgt/update action : ui.execute
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,467] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Role :  INTERNAL/admin
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,467] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  ADMIN user has permitted resource :  /permission/admin/manage/identity/usermgt/update, action :ui.execute
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,468] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Authorization cache miss for username : username01 resource /permission action : ui.execute
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,468] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Allowed roles for the ResourceID: /permission Action: ui.execute
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,468] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  role: INTERNAL/admin
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,468] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Roles which have permission for resource : /permission action : ui.execute
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,469] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Role :  INTERNAL/admin
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,469] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} -  Retrieving internal roles for user name :  username01 and search filter *
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,470] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user username01
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,544] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=username01)) in SearchBase: 
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,547] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Name in space for username01 is CN=USER NAME01,OU=DEPARTMENT,OU=EXAMPLE USERS,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,549] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: username01 exist: true
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,550] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Escaped DN value for filter : CN=USER NAME01,OU=DEPARTMENT,OU=EXAMPLE USERS,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,550] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Reading roles with the membershipProperty Property: member
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,550] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Result for searchBase: OU=EXAMPLE USERS,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM searchFilter: (&(objectcategory=group)(member=CN=USER NAME01,OU=DEPARTMENT,OU=EXAMPLE USERS,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM)) property:cn appendDN: false
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,627] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  username01 user has permitted resource :  /permission, action :ui.execute
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,627] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  username01 user is not Authorized to perform ui.execute on /permission
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,628] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Authorization cache miss for username : username01 resource /permission/admin action : ui.execute
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,628] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Allowed roles for the ResourceID: /permission/admin Action: ui.execute
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,628] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  role: INTERNAL/admin
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,628] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Roles which have permission for resource : /permission/admin action : ui.execute
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,628] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Role :  INTERNAL/admin
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,628] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  username01 user has permitted resource :  /permission/admin, action :ui.execute
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,628] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  username01 user is not Authorized to perform ui.execute on /permission/admin
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,640] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user username01
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,640] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  value after escaping special characters in username01 : username01
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,640] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: username01 exist: true
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,681] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} -  value after escaping special characters in USER NAME01 : USER NAME01
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,687] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} -  Can not access the directory service for user : username01
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100238, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'OU=EXAMPLE USERS,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM'
]; remaining name 'CN=USER NAME01'

    ...

[2017-08-18 17:00:02,970] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Authorization cache miss for username : ADMIN resource /permission/admin/login action : ui.execute
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,971] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Allowed roles for the ResourceID: /permission/admin/login Action: ui.execute
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,972] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  role: INTERNAL/admin
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,972] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  role: INTERNAL/everyone
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,972] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Roles which have permission for resource : /permission/admin/login action : ui.execute
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,972] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Role :  INTERNAL/admin
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,972] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Role :  INTERNAL/everyone
[2017-08-18 17:00:02,972] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  ADMIN user has permitted resource :  /permission/admin/login, action :ui.execute
```

(Hopefully I've sanitized these well enough...)

This is what the logs look like when one of those users logs in, and successfully changes their password:

```
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,471] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user username01
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,472] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  value after escaping special characters in username01 : username01
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,472] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: username01 exist: true
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,474] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user username01
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,474] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  value after escaping special characters in username01 : username01
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,474] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: username01 exist: true
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,474] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user username01
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,474] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  value after escaping special characters in username01 : username01
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,474] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: username01 exist: true
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,534] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=username01)) in SearchBase: 
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,535] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Requesting attribute :ref
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,547] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user username01
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,547] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  value after escaping special characters in username01 : username01
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,547] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: username01 exist: true
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,627] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=username01)) in SearchBase: 
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,627] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Requesting attribute :accountLock
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,632] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Authenticating user username01
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,632] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Cache hit. Using DN CN=USER NAME01,OU=DEPARTMENT,OU=EXAMPLE Users,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,705] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: CN=USER NAME01,OU=DEPARTMENT,OU=EXAMPLE Users,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM is authnticated: true
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,712] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Authenticating user username01
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,712] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Cache hit. Using DN CN=USER NAME01,OU=DEPARTMENT,OU=EXAMPLE Users,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM
[2017-08-18 17:21:27,783] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: CN=USER NAME01,OU=DEPARTMENT,OU=EXAMPLE Users,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM is authnticated: true
[2017-08-18 17:21:28,031] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Authorization cache hit. username01 user is not Authorized to perform ui.execute on /permission/admin/manage/identity
[2017-08-18 17:21:28,031] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Authorization cache hit. username01 user is not Authorized to perform ui.execute on /permission/admin/manage/identity/usermgt/users
[2017-08-18 17:21:28,031] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Authorization cache hit. username01 user is not Authorized to perform ui.execute on /permission/admin/manage/identity/usermgt/passwords
[2017-08-18 17:21:28,032] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Authorization cache hit. username01 user is not Authorized to perform ui.execute on /permission/admin/manage/identity/usermgt/profiles
```

And I've confirmed that the password actually does get changed in AD by doing a simple: Get-ADUser username01 -Properties *

Anyways, can someone point out what's wrong? We have a partner that is setting up a production version of this up for us, and theirs, while having other issues (hence me setting up my own local version to help test), theirs does allow both the users to log in and change their own passwords, as well as this ADMIN user to log in and change the passwords of those two users.

I even tried copying their user-mgt.xml into my local instance, and that didn't work either. The production version is 5.1.0 I think, and mine is 5.3.0, but so that might maybe be related.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

IS CN=ADMIN,OU=DEPARTMENT,OU=USERS,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM user has rights in AD to change password for other user. For best practice create a user with Domain control rights and try again.

Regards,
Tayyab

Comment: It does. As mentioned in my original description, "I've set up AD integration, and set up the LDAP bind account user with Delegated Control to reset passwords on a specific OU, and the objects therein." Note that I've given it "RESET PASSWORD" privileges in AD, NOT "CHANGE PASSWORD". The difference is that "CHANGE" is for the individual users themselves, and requires knowledge of the current password. "RESET" is an administrative function that an account with correct permissions can perform on another account, with no knowledge of that user's current password.

Comment: I also reject the idea, that giving blanket Domain Admin privileges should be considered best practice, in this situation. We are using this AD account for LDAP bind, and password management. Therefore, it does not need any further privileges than those. We do not allow it to create users or groups (or "roles", as WSO2 calls it). 

The same user account in question CAN perform "CHANGE" (again, in AD, it's "RESET") functions on users' accounts in our partner's implementation, note, *without* Domain Admin privileges, but it does not work when I copy their config into my test instance.